# writable create() method in drf serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

## serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

class VendorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = '__all__'
```

## views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class VendorViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VendorSerializer
    queryset = Vendor.objects.all()
```

How do I override  writable create() method on VendorSerializer to add products details to vendors where products are from the related to Vendor?

Comment: You said *each products are uniquely related to Vendor*, then why don't you try a `OnetoOne` relation?

Comment: I mean from Vendor form, it should be able to add many products.

Comment: can you add the post payload?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the built in [serializer create method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) but it may make more sense to deal with the object itself in a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save), that way you can access the ManyToMany objects fields.

Comment: I know but I am not being able to do that

Comment: Which one? there are two methods to solve the problem in my answer. Why are you unable to do both/either?